# Angular component template test at root level

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am learning angular devp with component , consider my web page has a single component as bellow

```
angular
  .module('mainPageModule', [])
  .component('mainPage', {
    templateUrl: 'mainPage.html',
    controller: mainPageController
  });
```

Controller code is :

```
class mainPageController{
   constructor(){
      let vm =this;
      vm.value=100;
   }
}
```

Html code : assume all angular ng-app and other stuff included here

```
<p>{{$ctrl.value}}</p>
```

I am trying to test this view as :

```js
describe('main page', () => {
  let element, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should verify some ', () => {
    element = angular.element('<main-page></main-page>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.value = 5000;
    scope.$apply();
    dump(element);
  });

});
```

`scope` is not getting applied to view and dumped element does not show value 5000.Please help in understanding how can I test this view (If any syntax error neglect that this is dummy example)

Answer (score 1):

You are binding values to controller, not scope. So in order to test a controller you don't really need to compile anything. All you need to do is to instantiate a component controller with [$componentController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$componentController) service and make sure it constructs properly.

For example expectation could look like this:

```
var $componentController;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
  $componentController = _$componentController_;
}));

it('should verify some ', () => {
  var controller = $componentController('mainPage');
  expect(controller.value).toBe(100);
});
```

Comment: I want to test is it displaying correct value on view (and i know it's unnecessary test as per the example but in my real example i need to test view behaviour  )

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your `value` manually for this test (as you test the template separately from the component):

```
element = angular.element('<main-page value="value"></main-page>');
```

In the case of a component, binding happens automatically (if it defined in a controller) or by `bindings` Component prop in case of an external source of value.